# Using Duende IdentityServer with a mix of clients, including Blazor WASM and ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

We have a legacy Web Forms app that we intend to slowly port over, module by module, to Blazor WASM. As we do not have the capacity to rebuild everything in Blazor straight away, we are going to have to run the Blazor and Web Forms app side by side for the time being. To the end user, this needs to appear seamless - i.e. they don't notice when they're being switched between the two.

The first thing I am trying to sort out is the log in process. We have decided to use IdentityServer to build an external identity provider which both the Blazor and Web Forms app will communicate with. Currently I am just trying to create some proof of concept models to see if I can actually get this to work.

I have managed to build a sample Blazor WASM app and a sample Web Forms app that both communicate with the same IdentityServer app to log in. Both of these apps recoginise upon initial load whether a user is already logged in to IdentityServer or not and they show or hide a claims page accordingly.

If I log out of the Web Forms app and then refresh the page in the Blazor app, the Blazor app requires me to log in again - which is what I want. I'm doing this by setting:

```
BackChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:7260/bff/backchannel"
```

in the IdentityServer `Config.cs` file for my Blazor client.

What I can't work out is how to get my Web Forms app to behave in a similar fashion. If I log out of my Blazor app, the Web Forms app remains signed in. I am not sure what the equivalent FrontChannelLogoutUri or BackChannelLogoutUri would be for the Web Forms app.

The Web Forms sample app I am using as my template is the sample provided by Duende themselves, which is here:

https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Samples/tree/main/various/clients/Owin

Answer (score 0):

(Firstly, these "technology migration" projects are tough , so I wish you the best of luck!)

You need a have two "Front channel server-side clients", so the `BackChannelLogoutUri` setting is useless. So you need to pay attention to [this part](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/ui/logout/notification/#front-channel-server-side-clients) of the Identity Server documentation.

Alternatively (as I have done the same in a similar project) you can call a service api in the other UI client and then use a technology like SignalR to notify all open browser tabs of the logging-out user in any other UI to trigger log out.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! Could I just ask - the BackChannelLogoutUri setting is working well for the Blazor client. Is it not possible to use both BackChannel for one app and FrontChannel for another? Do they have to be the same across all clients?

Comment: @HannahHayes you can use both, one for each app. It is a common scenario. So it does not have to be the same